# How to made SOAP request from Rhodes?, I don't want to use Rhoconnect

Tags: soap, rhodes

I am having my rhodes application. I would like to make SOAP request . I dont' want to make user of rhosync/rhoconnect. 
How can i found soap header and body please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can include a SOAP gem or ruby extension (such as [savon](https://github.com/rubiii/savon) or [soap4r](http://rubyforge.org/projects/soap4r/)) in your application, following [these instructions](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions#ruby-extensions), specifically under the heading for **Adding Ruby Extension Libraries to Your Rhodes Application**.

However, if you are not limited to SOAP, you may use the provided [AsyncHttp library](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/connect-to-web-services).